# Symfony 3: Undefined class constant 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR'

Tags: php, symfony, web

I'm working in an authentification system using Gard in symfony 3,

When I use

```
$request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);
```

inside

```
public onAuthenticationFailure()
```

I receive this error ***Undefined class constant 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR'***

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you forget to use the `Security` class or use an incorrect one.

try it:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
```